# Replacing letters as they are typed via a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm learning to create Chrome extensions and I would like to know if this is possible, and how it would be done.

There is forum for a game website that's unbelievably active and faced-paced, but its software is primitive. It allows nothing more than plaintext threads and replies.

Would it be possible for an extension to place toggle buttons next to the post input box that, when enabled, actively replace letters with their [bold and italic unicode counterparts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Alphanumeric_Symbols)?

Comment: Why dont you try the extensions like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eleots-content-editable-t/gmhkhdpgdcfnklclbomeomnmgdbgnokj?hl=en. This does not actually place a toggle button, but you can type bold and italic text using this.

Comment: @Mukund Grandlur - The description for that extension says that it's for input boxes that allow rich text formatting. The place I want formatted text doesn't allow rich text formatting. Instead of formatting the normal letters, I am trying to replace those letters with entirely different unicode symbols that look just like formatted versions of those letters. I included a link to the symbols I want to use at the end of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about how you would do this with a chrome extension, all of my experience with client-side modifications is with userscripts.

However, the JavaScript part of this is relatively straightforward.

### First, the nodes

We should get this out of the way first, it's pretty simple, select the node you want to listen to, create a couple checkboxes, mash it all together, you get the idea.

I'm not going too far into this because you haven't supplied any info about the HTML that you're going to be dealing with, but this is basic stuff.

```html
<input class="input">
```

```js
var nodes = {};

nodes.input = document.querySelector('.input');

nodes.bold  = (function()
{
    var label = document.createElement('label');
    nodes.input.parentNode.appendChild(label);

    var bold = document.createElement('input');
    label.appendChild(bold);
    bold.type = 'checkbox';

    var text = document.createTextNode('B');
    label.appendChild(text);

    return bold;
})();

nodes.ital  = (function()
{
    var label = document.createElement('label');
    nodes.input.parentNode.appendChild(label);

    var ital = document.createElement('input');
    label.appendChild(ital);
    ital.type = 'checkbox';

    var text = document.createTextNode('I');
    label.appendChild(text);

    return ital;
})();
```

### Next, the replacements dictionary.

So we need to make a dictionary object where we pair each letter with it's counter-part for a given modifier. I separated this into three objects: Bold, Ital, and BoldItal. This way we can dynamically figure out which style we are going to be replacing the letter with.

This could have been a really tedious job, but thanks to Chrome Dev Tools' element inspector and console, I was able to make short work of it.

```js
var replacements = {};

replacements.Bold     = {'a':'','b':'','c':'','d':'','e':'','f':'','g':'','h':'','i':'',
                         'j':'','k':'','l':'','m':'','n':'','o':'','p':'','q':'','r':'',
                         's':'','t':'','u':'','v':'','w':'','x':'','y':'','z':'',
                         'A':'','B':'','C':'','D':'','E':'','F':'','G':'','H':'','I':'',
                         'J':'','K':'','L':'','M':'','N':'','O':'','P':'','Q':'','R':'',
                         'S':'','T':'','U':'','V':'','W':'','X':'','Y':'','Z':''};



replacements.Ital     = {'a':'','b':'','c':'','d':'','e':'','f':'','g':'','h':'','i':'',
                         'j':'','k':'','l':'','m':'','n':'','o':'','p':'','q':'','r':'',
                         's':'','t':'','u':'','v':'','w':'','x':'','y':'','z':'',
                         'A':'','B':'','C':'','D':'','E':'','F':'','G':'','H':'','I':'',
                         'J':'','K':'','L':'','M':'','N':'','O':'','P':'','Q':'','R':'',
                         'S':'','T':'','U':'','V':'','W':'','X':'','Y':'','Z':''};

replacements.BoldItal = {'a':'','b':'','c':'','d':'','e':'','f':'','g':'','h':'','i':'',
                         'j':'','k':'','l':'','m':'','n':'','o':'','p':'','q':'','r':'',
                         's':'','t':'','u':'','v':'','w':'','x':'','y':'','z':'',
                         'A':'','B':'','C':'','D':'','E':'','F':'','G':'','H':'','I':'',
                         'J':'','K':'','L':'','M':'','N':'','O':'','P':'','Q':'','R':'',
                         'S':'','T':'','U':'','V':'','W':'','X':'','Y':'','Z':''};
```

### Finally, the listener function.

This is also pretty simple, attach an event listener to the input element.

If the value of `e.which` is less than 65 or greater than 90, it isn't a letter.

If neither of the modifier nodes are checked, we don't need to do anything.

Create the modifier variable, then build it based on the checked modifier checkboxes. We have to do this in a specific order so that if both are checked the result is `BoldItal` as we defined in the dictionary above.

Get the letter from the character code supplied by `e.which` using `String.fromCharCode`. This will always supply us with an uppercase letter, so we have to check if the shift key was pressed using `e.shiftKey`, which will be true if pressed, false otherwise.

Prevent the default action so that the actual key pressed does not do anything, then append the replacement to the input.

```js
nodes.input.addEventListener('keydown', function(e)
{
    if (e.which < 65 || e.which > 90)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (!nodes.bold.checked && !nodes.ital.checked)
    {
        return;
    }

    var modifier = '';

    if (nodes.bold.checked)
    {
        modifier += 'Bold';
    }

    if (nodes.ital.checked)
    {
        modifier += 'Ital';
    }

    var search = String.fromCharCode(e.which);

    if (!e.shiftKey)
    {
        search = search.toLowerCase();
    }

    e.preventDefault();

    nodes.input.value += replacements[modifier][search];
}, false);
```

### Put it all together.

Here's the whole shebang in a demo. It should be pretty simple to adapt this to a Chrome Extension or userscript.

```js
var nodes = {};

nodes.input = document.querySelector('.input');

nodes.bold  = (function()
{
    var label = document.createElement('label');
    nodes.input.parentNode.appendChild(label);
    
    var bold = document.createElement('input');
    label.appendChild(bold);
    bold.type = 'checkbox';
    
    var text = document.createTextNode('B');
    label.appendChild(text);
    
    return bold;
})();

nodes.ital  = (function()
{
    var label = document.createElement('label');
    nodes.input.parentNode.appendChild(label);
    
    var ital = document.createElement('input');
    label.appendChild(ital);
    ital.type = 'checkbox';
    
    var text = document.createTextNode('I');
    label.appendChild(text);
    
    return ital;
})();

var replacements = {};

replacements.Bold     = {'a':'','b':'','c':'','d':'','e':'','f':'','g':'','h':'','i':'',
                         'j':'','k':'','l':'','m':'','n':'','o':'','p':'','q':'','r':'',
                         's':'','t':'','u':'','v':'','w':'','x':'','y':'','z':'',
                         'A':'','B':'','C':'','D':'','E':'','F':'','G':'','H':'','I':'',
                         'J':'','K':'','L':'','M':'','N':'','O':'','P':'','Q':'','R':'',
                         'S':'','T':'','U':'','V':'','W':'','X':'','Y':'','Z':''};
                     
                     
                     
replacements.Ital     = {'a':'','b':'','c':'','d':'','e':'','f':'','g':'','h':'','i':'',
                         'j':'','k':'','l':'','m':'','n':'','o':'','p':'','q':'','r':'',
                         's':'','t':'','u':'','v':'','w':'','x':'','y':'','z':'',
                         'A':'','B':'','C':'','D':'','E':'','F':'','G':'','H':'','I':'',
                         'J':'','K':'','L':'','M':'','N':'','O':'','P':'','Q':'','R':'',
                         'S':'','T':'','U':'','V':'','W':'','X':'','Y':'','Z':''};
                     
replacements.BoldItal = {'a':'','b':'','c':'','d':'','e':'','f':'','g':'','h':'','i':'',
                         'j':'','k':'','l':'','m':'','n':'','o':'','p':'','q':'','r':'',
                         's':'','t':'','u':'','v':'','w':'','x':'','y':'','z':'',
                         'A':'','B':'','C':'','D':'','E':'','F':'','G':'','H':'','I':'',
                         'J':'','K':'','L':'','M':'','N':'','O':'','P':'','Q':'','R':'',
                         'S':'','T':'','U':'','V':'','W':'','X':'','Y':'','Z':''};

nodes.input.addEventListener('keydown', function(e)
{
    if (e.ctrlKey || e.which < 65 || e.which > 90)
    {
        return;
    }
    
    if (!nodes.bold.checked && !nodes.ital.checked)
    {
        return;
    }
    
    var modifier = '';
    
    if (nodes.bold.checked)
    {
        modifier += 'Bold';
    }
    
    if (nodes.ital.checked)
    {
        modifier += 'Ital';
    }
    
    var search = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    
    if (!e.shiftKey)
    {
        search = search.toLowerCase();
    }
    
    e.preventDefault();
    
    nodes.input.value += replacements[modifier][search];
}, false);
```

```html
<input class="input">
```

Comment: Unbelievably detailed and informative answer. Thank you so much!